# FPDF Cell command draws bottom border through centre of text

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to add a section title to a PDF page which is underlined so I'm adding a page-width sized Cell and wanting to underline it so I'm doing this:

```
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 12);
$pdf->SetXY(5, $y);
$pdf->Cell(195, 0, $qrow['Title'], "B", 1, "L");
```

However what comes out is more like a "strikethrough" effect where the bottom line of the cell passes through all the text.

[image]

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: No I think you are drawing your text over the top of the lines

Comment: Sure but I thought that specifying the "B" parameter in Cell should draw a Bottom edge of the cell in which the text is rendered?

Comment: Try and set the Y coord to zero, its probably that that is painting the text below the line

Comment: If I set the Y coord to zero the Cell comes out at the top of the page rather than where I want it...

Comment: Sorry its a year or more since I used FPDF I am a bit rusty

Answer (score 0):

Since the `line height parameter` is set to `zero`, the line is over the text.

Set the height as below, which will fix the problem:

```
$pdf->Cell(195, 10, $qrow['Title'], "B", 1, "L");
```